# How do I make the hover event work properly?

Tags: html, css

I have a P tag that I made hidden with css. When I access the hover event of the div, I make this tag appear, but then the link doesn't work. The link that is exactly inside the tag.
What am I doing wrong?

```css
.card-wrapper p:nth-child(2){
  margin: 0;  
  visibility: visible;  
}
.card-wrapper p:nth-child(3){
  margin: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.card-wrapper h2{
  font-size: 40px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  margin: 0;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.card:hover > .card-wrapper::before{
    height: 130px;
    width: 350px;
    opacity: 1;
    box-shadow: 3px 2px 2px rgb(85, 81, 81);

}
.card:hover > .card-wrapper p:nth-child(3){
    visibility: visible;    
    opacity: 1;
}
.card:hover > .card-wrapper p:nth-child(2){
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}
.card:hover > .card-wrapper a{
    visibility: visible;
}
.card:hover > .card-wrapper h2{
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgb(59, 57, 57);
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-wrapper">
        <h2>Github</h2>
        <p>Veja meus projetos!</p>
        <p>
            <a href="https://www.google.com.br/"
            title="Acessar GitHub">
            Ao clicar aqui vc vai acessar meus projetos!
            </a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tested it locally and it's working. Where you are execution your code? For example it wouldn't work in the above snippet here at Stack Overflow.

Comment: I'm using VsCOde's Live Server plugin. But even running otherwise in another browser doesn't work.

Comment: I tested your code also with VsCOde's Live Server plugin, and it's working on Safari, Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: This div is inside a container with display:flex parameter. Could there be something related to this?

Comment: Your code works fine when I run it locally. It won't work in the SO snippet system because google doesn't allow its website to be run in an iframe. I don't know whether you meant the br/ at the end of the url?

Answer (score 1):

I achieved
I just needed to set the position parameter to relative.

```
.card:hover > .card-wrapper a {
position: relative;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

your link will be working, if you open your link another window, just simply use this code, Hope it will help you

```
<a href="https://www.google.com.br/"
            title="Acessar GitHub" target="_blank">
            Ao clicar aqui vc vai acessar meus projetos!
            </a>
```

Comment: Did not working!